# Trigger Kernel Interrupt Handler: How?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel, interrupt-handling

[image]I am trying to understand Asynchronous Interrupt handling in kernel, ofcourse through the legendary Understanding the Linux Kernel.

In this process how and who will trigger Kernel Interrupt Handler?

I would like some one to help me correcting this and to clarify my question on 
1)How and Who trigger Kernel Interrupt Handler? 
2)How to define new or change existing hardware interrupt handlers?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Interrupt handling]
This picture from Robert Love's "Linux Kernel Development" pretty well describes path of interrupt. Processor interrupts the kernel in the predefined enty point `do_IRQ()`. If there is corresponding interrupt handler, it will get executed.

To handle interrupt, you should register your interrupt handler with `request_irq()`.

Comment: Coolest! Thanks rasen... This also has an reference for creating interrupt handlers. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Keen Learner: Now you have it ;-)

Comment: @KeenLearner acceptance of answer does not require 15 points. 15 points for upwote, but you can freely accept answer on question you ask.