# How would one go about generating "artificial" interrupts in the Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've read the answer here: [Trigger Kernel Interrupt Handler: How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783022/trigger-kernel-interrupt-handler-how) and it's a good one, but not quite what I need.

I'm microbenchmarking the RNG functions in regards to processing interrupts, so I need a good way to **artificially and repeatably** generate interrupts. For example, I could redirect something into a Procfs interface that generates 300 interrupts or something like that.

Is it as easy as running some kind of function in the kernel that generates an interrupt?

Is there some kind of interrupt that does not actually do "Anything", but still goes through the entire interrupt handler path? I realize I could just type keys or something like that but that's not really repeatable and scriptable for research purposes.

I'm working with the x86 architecture.

Comment: You want to simulate hardware interrupts or would just syscalls be enough ? Are you running in kernel space ? Do you care what interrupt gets executed or is any hardware interrupt fine ?

Comment: Well, it's architecture-dependent, but most provide for software-generated interrupts.  It's one way of implementing syscalls.

Comment: @tux3 I'm not positive... would syscalls go through the entire interrupt path, including the functions in /drivers/char/random.c? If so, then that's perfect. Just an `INT` in x86?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm working with x86, I'll put that in the OP.

Comment: Are there any peripheral timers you could use? Something akin to watchdog timers?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Then no, syscalls won't work. Only interrupt handlers installed with SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM will generate entropy. Such as keyboard interrupts.

Comment: @tux3 thanks! That's great. Do you have any specific example of an interrupt I could call (either from kernelspace or userspace) repeatedly that wouldn't panic, for benchmarking purposes? If you write it as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as best answer.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I'll write an answer on how to generate fake keyboard interrupts that look real. It's not tested, but that's the best I have on the spot.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a potential solution that generates fake keyboard interrupts, from the PoV of the kernel there's no way to tell that these interrupts aren't real.

Only interrupt handlers installed with SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM will generate entropy, this eliminates syscalls for this purpose. However keyboard interrupts do generate entropy.

I have not tested the following code, and can't offer any guarantees, but I believe that it should work if ran as part of a kernel module.

The following snippet of code shows how to forcefully inject a key into the keyboard controller's buffer. This will not work if a real PS/2 keyboard (or USB keyboard with Legacy USB support in BIOS) is not plugged in. [This code was copied from a SMM keylogger article on Phrack](http://phrack.org/issues/66/11.html)

The code is in x86 assembly, you can wrap it in an inline assembly block `asm("");` if you write your kernel module in C.

```
; write command byte 0xD2 to command port 0x64
; to re-inject intercepted scan code into keyboard controller buffer
; so that OS keyboard interrupt can read and display it later
mov al, 0xd2
out 0x64, al
; wait until keyboard controller is ready to read
_wait:
in al, 0x64
test al, 0x2
jnz _wait
; re-inject scan code for the key '1' 
mov ax, 1
out 0x60, al
```

Then to generate the keyboard interrupt do :

```
int 33
```

Interrupt 33 is typically the PS/2 keyboard. This will cause Linux to handle the keyboard interrupt, read our fake scancode, and generate some randomness for you.
You will want to call this in a loop, but be careful, Linux generates randomness based in part on the interval between two interrupts, if you force interrupts at fixed intervals, you will get very little entropy out of this method.

Note that it should also work if you do just `asm("int $33")` without running the first part of the code, but that might confuse the kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and report back when I do.

Comment: I'm getting a ton of errors trying to write this code in inline asm. Is there any chance you could help me see what I'm doing wrong with writing this? Here's an example line: 
`mov %al, $0xd2\n`, and I get `unsupported instruction mov`

Comment: Ah, the AT&T syntax and Intel syntax are reversed. `mov al, 0xd2` translates to `mov $0xD2, %al;`. Have you tried with just the `int $33` first ? It's possible that it'll work by itself.

Comment: Thanks much for the help! I got it to compile and run. However, it's not actually adding interrupts (at least not the entropy-eligible ones). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I suppose you could call add_interrupt_randomness manually with some made up data as a last resort.

Comment: I might do that, yeah. Do you know how I'd find other interrupts to call with `INT x` ? Preferably one that would go through the entire path?

Comment: You could look at the files around `arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h` and grep interesting vectors from there I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Just start a high-resolution timer:

```
struct hrtimer timer;

hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
timer.function = my_little_timer;
hrtimer_start(&timer, ktime_set(0, 500000000 /* ns */), HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

...

hrtimer_cancel(&timer);

...

enum hrtimer_restart my_little_timer(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
    // either:
    hrtimer_forward_now(timer, ktime_set(...));
    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
    // or:
    return HRTIMER_NORESTART;
}
```

Comment: Back in the office today, I'll give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I threw this code in, got it to compile and run, but I'm not seeing any interrupts. Am I missing something? Trying to read docs online, but they aren't really helping.