# how to test effectiveness of preempt_rt patch?

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, stress-testing, preempt-rt

I'm doing a study to compare the linux default kernel with the kernel patched with preempt_rt.
I used a lot of tools (stress-ng, T-Sui, CPU burn, cycletest) to check the effectiveness of the patch. But I can see that the default kernel does already provide a method to change the tasks priority to a "real-time-task". Therefore, all of the stress-tests show a similar result: my application is always performed as real-time task without any strong delays or something different surprising...

I know some differences that preempt_rt causes (like interrupts moved to thread context, less non-preemtive code in kernel) but **how do I test them??**
I've seen that the normal stress-tools show almost no impact on my real-time-application... **Is there any tool to execute a kind of "high-non-preemtive-kernel-code" or that triggers a huge amount of interrupts?**

Comment: You can always see if [scheduler-tools](https://github.com/scheduler-tools) fits your purpose, specially [rt-app](https://github.com/scheduler-tools/rt-app). An option to test your application is to generate artificial interrupts with higher priority than your application and observe the impact in terms of schedulability and jitter.

Comment: @CRM How do I generate artificial interrupts?

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865075/how-would-one-go-about-generating-artificial-interrupts-in-the-linux-kernel) post you may find different alternatives to do that.

Comment: Have you managed to succeed with this?